# Why is Mongoid not sending slaveOk to mongos in a sharded environment?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, sharding

I can fire off queries from the 'mongos' console,  and see the reads hit the primaries.  I can successfully execute `rs.slaveOk();` and then fire off the same queries, and see the reads hit the secondaries.

The problem is that no matter what I try I can't get queries in [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/) to hit the secondaries. It appears that it's not sending the `slaveOk`.  I've tried setting `read: :secondary` in *mongoid.yml*, and I've also tried `read_secondary: true`,  but the underlying connection is not a replica set one, so I'm thinking that's why mongoid is ignoring it.

Is there some other way (barring just creating my own connection pool and setting `:slave_ok`) that I can get mongoid to work? Am I missing some magical undocumented yml setting?

Answer (score 2):

Since Mongoid is connecting to a single mongos router, just add the following line below the hostname entry in mongoid.yml:

```
slave_ok: true
```

Comment: Our real problem was that in the mongoid yml we were specifying 'host' instead of 'hosts'.  We thought we just needed a 'host' specification since we're only talking to mongos locally.  However,  this causes the connection to be established as a regular mongo connection, instead of a replica set connection,  and thus the slaveOk was not being sent.